# AWS Braket Backend for Qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, amazon-braket

Is there a working AWS Braket backend provider for Qiskit 0.29 that can be used with the MinimumEigenOptimizer interface? The qiskit-aws-braket-provider package is unfortunately not working.

Comment: There is a new qiskit-braket-plugin that is being actively developed under Qiskit Advocate Mentorship Program. It might be useful for you after it's initial release, probably in a few months: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-plugin

Answer (score 3):

#### qbraid does!

qbraid has a transpiler for Qiskit <> Braket <> Pennylane (QNodes) <> Cirq <> Pyquil which is also backend compatible.

You'll have to sign up to access the SDK which can be done @ https://qbraid.com (it's free). The SDK should also have an opensource version at some point. Stay tuned!

##### Gaining access to the qBraid-transpiler

In terms of accessing the qbraid-sdk they have a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXpS29HrdgY) which can get you started with credits etc for free! However, the qbraid CLI is frequently updated and checking the syntax to access various QCs (Rigetti, IONQ, OQC etc) by typing `qbraid -h` might be necessary in your qBraid Lab terminal.

They provide documentation for how their transpiler works [here](https://qbraid-qbraid.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/sdk/overview.html).

Check out the [demo repo](https://github.com/qBraid/qbraid-lab-demo) and an [example](https://github.com/SoranaAurelia/QCHack-2022/blob/main/intro_to_qc_challenges/grovers_algorithm/QuantumCrew_Grovers_Challange.ipynb) from QCHack  as well!

Hope this helps and if you have any questions just message me :)

The repository is now open source:
https://github.com/qbraid/qbraid

Answer (score 2):

As a general follow-up on this question the qiskit-braket provider, https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider, mentioned earlier is actively monitored and maintained by both the open-source community as well as people at IBM and Amazon Braket. If there are limitations or bugs that you encounter when running Qiskit on Amazon Braket via that provider it is worth raising as an Issue in that GitHub repository.